# Can I get access to a full block in the mapper?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

Usually record reader passes line by line to the mapper or n lines. Can full block be accessed in the mapper? This means the record reader will give full block to the mapper instead of line by line? Does this approach makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the entire block at once? because a mapper will read one block in it's entirety anyway.

Comment: Yes the entire block. Usually the entire block is read line by line or by some other record criteria.

Comment: I think you need to implement custom `InputFormat` to your block size will be equal to split size.

Answer (score 1):

Need to note that split size is not equal to block size by default. To do what you want you need to implement custom [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) and to be more exact method `getSplits(JobContext context)`. And make `InputSplit` size to be equal to block size.